# How can I detect if an incoming HTTP request is a redirect in Flask web application?

Tags: python, flask, redirect, request, response

I am currently working on a Flask web application and currently am trying to add a custom conditional to my home route to perform different behavior if an incoming request is coming from a redirect.

The proposed logic would be as follows:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    
    if <REQUEST_IS_REDIRECT>:
        # do some stuff
    else:
        # do some different stuff
    
    # do some stuff always
```

Is there a way I can easily determine if the incoming request is a redirect? I can't seem to find anything directly referencing this issue.

I tried researching the Flask.request class but none of the attributes of said object seemed to provide the data I wanted. I also couldn't seem to find anything on Flask.redirect that included requests. I could only find stuff pertaining to Flask.response, which I thought could be helpful but I didn't seem to be able to use response in any meaningful way.

Comment: You can't. You should make a separate route for the redirect instead.

Comment: If you are the one making the redirect, you can set a custom header and check for this custom header in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect that a request was the result of a redirect. This is not specific to Flask. HTTP is stateless, so it does not know what happened previously with any requests or responses.

Instead, you can make a different route for the redirect. Put any shared logic in a function which both routes can call.